# Can not update a component while rendering a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, conditional-statements

I am using the `useAuth` hook to my `authContext`, so that I can use hook to set global states for my components.

Now, I am trying to navigate to the `'/'` page if the user was not logged in, and also display a `requireLoginAlert` to the user in the `'/'` page after the user was redirected. However, I got the following error when I try to include the `setRequireLoginAlert(true)` function in `requireAuth.js`.

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`AuthProvider`) while rendering a different component (`RequireAuth`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `RequireAuth`
```

My `requireAuth.js`:

```
const RequireAuth = () => {
  const { auth, setRequireLoginAlert } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    auth?.user 
      ? <Outlet />
      : <Navigate to='/' state={{ from: location }} replace />
      && setRequireLoginAlert(true)
  );
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

My `AuthContext.js`

```
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});
  const [requireLoginAlert, setRequireLoginAlert] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth, requireLoginAlert, setRequireLoginAlert }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

I have try using `useEffect` the display the alert whenever the `location` has changed, but in this way the alert will keep popping out whenever I go to other pages, which is not ideal. I need a trigger to change the `requireLoginAlert` state after the user was redirected without error.

Feel free the drop a comment if you have any idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't that error popping up because you return the Navigate component and calling a function from your context? Maybe move that call to the useEffect and in the return only render the component

Comment: yes it is, this is the exact problem! I have solved it through useEffect for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the good way with the useEffect approach.

Indeed you have use the location in the dependencies array, but you also need to include a condition based on the current page so that the `requireLoginAlert` is not called every time

Have you tried something like the following piece of code ?

```js
useEffect(
  () => auth?.user && location === "/" && setRequireLoginAlert(true),
  [auth?.user, location]
);
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I have created a useEffect like this: ` useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth?.user && location.pathname === '/home/')
      setRequireLoginAlert(true);
  }, [auth?.user, location]);` It work fine. Not sure if I will find error in future since I am doing a multi-page website. Thanks for sharing!